# Search multiple table columns for the same value

Tags: sql, dql, documentum-dql

I would like to replicate what our database search engine calls a 'multi-field search' in DQL (which is pretty much SQL as I understand).

I'm not sure if this is possible, but the syntax would look something like...

```
SELECT title, container_no, archive_status 
FROM record_table 
WHERE * like 'search term'
```

Can it be done? Surely there must be a better way than having a string of...

```
WHERE column1 = "search term" OR
column2 = "search term" OR
column3 = "search term" OR
etc...
```

If this were possible, I envisage it would look something like this:

```
WHERE (column1, column2, column3, column4) like '%search term%'
```

Edit 1: Updated pseudo code for clarity

Edit 2: Added additional thoughts

Comment: Are you looking for `AND` oor `OR`?

Comment: Full-text search maybe ?

Comment: Updated question: I was looking for OR!

Comment: Problems like this often indicate a poor db design.

Comment: Multiple *or* conditions are likely to not be performant and other approaches could be better.

Comment: Couldn't agree more, but that's what I've got to work with!

Comment: @jarlh Can be old database design too, since they were much more limited by the amounts of characters used.

Comment: @Tilen, in many cases such design wastes disk space.

Comment: @jarlh Yes, which I never disagreed with. Old design is poor design, yet sometimes we have to work with it.

Comment: You could create a DQL-Extension: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/cookbook/dql-custom-walkers.html Or just `x.prop1 = :search_term OR x.prop2 = :search_term ...`